# Wrapper won't take up full space

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

My css wrapper class only applies to what is displayed. I'm using Angular and have an *ngIf in my html to display some cards after options are selected from my dropdown. Once options are selected and the cards are displayed, my wrapper (with red background) extends to apply to the now-displayed cards.

I want my wrapper to always be seen no matter what, from top to bottom. I am happy with the width as that looks how I want it to.

Structure here goes as follows: "index.html" contains "app.component.html" which contains "venues.component.html".

[Before cards are displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pToAo.png)

[After cards are displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pkad.png)

**css:**

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* background-color: rgb(223, 223, 223); */
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

**index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/flatly/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Whoknows</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script>
    var global = global || window;
    var Buffer = Buffer || [];
    var process = process || {
      env: { DEBUG: undefined },
      version: []
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <app-root></app-root>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<html>
  <!-- <app-nav></app-nav> -->
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="homeMessage lead">
        <p>Select which venues you'd like to see shows for</p>
      </div>
      <br>
      <app-venue-cards></app-venue-cards>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**venues.component.html:**

```
<div>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
  </head>
  <!-- <header>
    <img src="../../../pianoHeader.jpg" class="img-header">
  </header> -->
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="center">
        <button (click)="displayCards()" class="btn btn-dark">Show my upcoming shows!</button>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="center">
        <ng-multiselect-dropdown
          name="venue"
          [placeholder]="'Select Venues...'"
          [data]="venueList"
          formControlName="venue"
          [settings]="dropdownSettings"
          (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
          (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
          (onDeSelect)="onItemDeSelect($event)"
        >
        </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="container">
        <div *ngFor='let show of showsToDisplay'>
          <h6>{{ show.venue.displayName }}</h6>
          <div class="card card:hover mb-2 rounded">
            <img id="cardImage" [src]="show.uri" class="card-image">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="col-md-12 ellipsis">
                <h3>{{ show.performance[0].artist.displayName }}</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <h5 class="text-secondary ellipsis" [ngClass]="{'hidden': !show.performance[1]}">{{ show.performance[1] ? show.performance[1].artist.displayName :  'a' }}</h5>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <h6 class="text-secondary ellipsis" [ngClass]="{'hidden': !show.performance[2]}">{{ show.performance[2] ? show.performance[2].artist.displayName :  'a' }}</h6>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                  <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
                  <h6>{{ show.start.date | date}}</h6>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark tixbtn">Tickets</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</div>
```

Comment: tried witdth:100%;height:100%; ?

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say that adding "height: 100%" to the .wrapper class fixed this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add height 100% to the .wrapper class